# If borderVisible is set on dynamically created textarea, text becomes invisible. AS3/Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I got a problem.
When I try to set the border of a dynamically created text area, to invisible using:

textArea.setStyle("borderVisible", "false"), the text disappears.

I looks like a bug. Have you any solution?

Answer (score 0):

textArea doesn't have 'borderVisible' style, you can set 'borderThickness' zero

`textArea.setStyle('borderThickness', 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was trying to set a style on the textArea. When I took out this line, the text showed up fine:

```
textArea.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xFFFFFF);
```